# Finding a date and replacing a word - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code as below where i am filtering out dates which are older then 2 days and making it bold and changing it's color.

In this I also want to replace the **Warning** to ****Failed**** where the date found is older then 2 days.

Can anyone please help how we can achieve it through below code.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
ht ="""<tr>
<td>32356</td>
<td>cfra03</td>
<td>04-07-2020</td>
<td>Ssv</td>
<td>Warning</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>32367</td>
<td>c017</td>
<td>04-08-2020</td>
<td>SDR</td>
<td>Completed</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>29451</td>
<td>c10</td>
<td>04-05-2020</td>
<td>SR</td>
<td>Warning</td>
</tr>
"""

date_var = re.findall(r"[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{4}", ht)
for s in date_var:
    element_date = datetime.strptime(s, "%m-%d-%Y")
    if (datetime.now() - element_date).days > 2:
        ht = ht.replace(s, '<b><font color="#ff0000">'+s+'</font></b>')
print (ht)
```

current output is-

```
<tr>
<td>32356</td>
<td>cfra03</td>
<td>04-07-2020</td>
<td>Ssv</td>
<td>Warning</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>32367</td>
<td>c017</td>
<td>04-08-2020</td>
<td>SDR</td>
<td>Completed</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>29451</td>
<td>c10</td>
<td><b><font color="#ff0000">04-05-2020</font></b></td>
<td>SR</td>
<td>Warning</td>
</tr>
```

Output should be-

```
<tr>
<td>32356</td>
<td>cfra03</td>
<td>04-07-2020</td>
<td>Ssv</td>
<td>Warning</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>32367</td>
<td>c017</td>
<td>04-08-2020</td>
<td>SDR</td>
<td>Completed</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>29451</td>
<td>c10</td>
<td><b><font color="#ff0000">04-05-2020</font></b></td>
<td>SR</td>
<td><b><font color="#ff0000">Failed</font></b></td>
</tr>
'''
```

Comment: I think you're doing wrong in `ht = ht.replace(s, '<b><font color="#ff0000">'+s+'</font></b>')` as you want replace "Warning" to "Failed" you need to do `ht = ht.replace(Warning,Failed)`

Comment: You have a dependency of two `<td>`s which have to be changed inside one `<tr>`. So it's better to get the table rows first, and then change both cells only if the date field matches your criterion. It's difficult to get this done by regular expressions, you may have to use parsing, i.e. iterate over each `<tr>` first and then see if criterion is made, then apply for example two replacements, e.g. with regular expressions.

Comment: No, along with date I also need to replace Warning with Failed where the date found is older then 2 days...with this code it is only updating the date(marking it with bold and colour) but how can i also replace Warning with Failed?
Please see output above what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
ht ="""<tr>
<td>32356</td>
<td>cfra03</td>
<td>04-07-2020</td>
<td>Ssv</td>
<td>Warning</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>32367</td>
<td>c017</td>
<td>04-08-2020</td>
<td>SDR</td>
<td>Completed</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>29451</td>
<td>c10</td>
<td>04-05-2020</td>
<td>SR</td>
<td>Warning</td>
</tr>
"""

result = []
rows = ht.split('<tr>')
for row in rows :
    date_var = re.findall(r"[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{4}", row, re.DOTALL)
    for s in date_var:
        element_date = datetime.strptime(s, "%m-%d-%Y")
        if (datetime.now() - element_date).days > 2:
            row = row.replace(s, '<b><font color="#ff0000">'+s+'</font></b>')
            row = row.replace( 'Warning', 'Failed') # or whatever
    result.append(row)

print ('<tr>'.join(result))
```

gives this result:

```
<tr>
<td>32356</td>
<td>cfra03</td>
<td>04-07-2020</td>
<td>Ssv</td>
<td>Warning</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>32367</td>
<td>c017</td>
<td>04-08-2020</td>
<td>SDR</td>
<td>Completed</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>29451</td>
<td>c10</td>
<td><b><font color="#ff0000">04-05-2020</font></b></td>
<td>SR</td>
<td>Failed</td>
</tr>
```

You may add HTML around `Failed` as you like.